# How to use Toggle Button to change the Onclick of a Button

Tags: javascript, android-studio

Hi i have a Toggle Button whereby when this button is toggled, i will set my other Next Button on-click to this

```
public void shuffleSong(View view)
    {
        //Call shuffle  in the Songcollection
        Song shuffle = SongCollection.shufflefunction(songId);

        songId = shuffle.getId();
        title = shuffle.getTitle();
        artist = shuffle.getArtist();
        fileLink = shuffle.getFileLink();
        coverArt = shuffle.getCoverArt();
        album=shuffle.getAlbum();

        url = BASE_URL + fileLink;

        displaySong(title, artist, coverArt);

        stopActivities();

        playOrPauseMusic(new View(this));


    }
```

And when the Button is not toggled, i want to set my Next Button onclick to this

```
 public void playNext(View view)
        {
            Song nextSong = SongCollection.getNextSong(songId);
            if (nextSong != null) {
                songId = nextSong.getId();
                title = nextSong.getTitle();
                artist = nextSong.getArtist();
                fileLink = nextSong.getFileLink();
                coverArt = nextSong.getCoverArt();
                album=nextSong.getAlbum();

                url = BASE_URL + fileLink;

                displaySong(title, artist, coverArt);

                stopActivities();

                playOrPauseMusic(view);
            }

        }
```

However i have no idea how to do this

Comment: The thing that i am unsure of now is how to do code this toggle button so that i can do so?

Answer (score 0):

To detect when the user activates the button or switch, create an CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener object and assign it to the button by calling setOnCheckedChangeListener(). For example:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled, do whatever you want to do here
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled, do whatever you want to do here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi i understand this part actually, but how do i write it so that if this button is checked, it will set the onclick of Next button to shuffleSong and when it is not checked, it will set the onclick of Next Button to playNext